# How to cancel a Stripe subscription price change?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

The customer, through the checkout page, subscribes to the product at "price 1". He has 3D confirmation on the card!!! He later states his desire to change the price to "price 2". I use the following code to implement this:

```
try {
    $subscription->anchorBillingCycleOn()->swapAndInvoice($plan_id);
 } catch (IncompletePayment $exception) {
    return redirect()->route('cashier.payment', [$exception->payment->id, 'redirect' => route('subscription.success')]);
}
```

The subscription price is updated and the invoice is marked as "pending", and the customer is redirected to the payment confirmation page.
And then the customer changed his mind and did not confirm the payment. For example, he saw that he chose the wrong price. The subscription is considered inactive.

How can I cancel/delete the last invoice and return to the previous subscription price?

Comment: [Pending update feature](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/pending-updates) is recommended in this case which the subscription can only be updated when the payment of the prorated invoice is completed, so that you don't have to handle the return to previous subscription price.

Comment: @yuting I cannot demand payment of an invoice if the customer changes his mind about buying a product at this price

Comment: If the invoice is not paid, then the subscription won't be updated to the new plan if you use [pending update feature](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/pending-updates). In case if the customer changes his mind, you can then void the prorated invoice. The subscription will remain as the old plan and no further action is required from you.